# How to escape special characters in xml attribute using python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I was wondering how it is possible to escape special characters in
an xml.

The following example fails sadly:

```
xml ="""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <Render value="a &lt b"/>
"""
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
p = ET.fromstring(xml)
```

**Output:**
`ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 2, column 28`

What is the easiest way round this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong escaping!

Try

`<Render value="a &lt; b"/>`

And everything works fine!